# Magento 2.3.2 PayPal Payflow Payment failed

Tags: paypal, magento2

When a customer places an order from the shop (Magento 2.3.2) using PayPal PayFlow Credit Card payment method but sometimes payment failed for some of the customers and there is no any message displaying on the checkout page.

When place order button hit PayPal generates the secure token to for the further transaction. Let me explain you step by step.

1. Place order button hit
2. PayPal generates securetoken and securetokenid
3. PayPal authorize the transaction with AMT : 0
4. PayPal response with the error message on step : 3 requests.

'RESPMSG' => 'Field format error: 10004-The transaction id is not valid',

I see the API docs from the PayPal but PayPal not stated clearly any specific error message. They have written generic error message. Please check in this screen shot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnEX0.png

If anyone help on this to know exact reason for the transaction failed that will help us or customer to understand in better way rather then to show a generic message from the PayPal error message.

Looking forward to hearing for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you contact support for this issue as changes were put in place due to rate limiting and other item for merchants who are on Magento due to this issue, https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025515991-PayPal-Payflow-Pro-active-carding-activity.